# How to create custom service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$scope.getData = function() {
    $http.get("../send")
        .then(function(response) {
                $scope.text = response.data;
                $scope.params = $scope.text.split(' ');
                $scope.timeFunc();
            },
            function(response) {
                $scope.timeFunc();
            });
};
$scope.timeFunc = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.getData();
    }, 1000);
};

$scope.getData();

});
```

How this can be done, not in the controller, and that it was a separate service?
The problem is that the variable `params` should be updated every second

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, servicenName) {
 $scope.getData = function () {
  servicenName.getData().then(function (response) {
   $scope.text = response.data;
   $scope.params = $scope.text.split(' ');
   $scope.timeFunc();
  },
   function (response) {
   $scope.timeFunc();
  });
 };

 $scope.timeFunc = function () {
  $timeout(function () {
   $scope.getData();
  }, 1000);
 };
 $scope.getData();
});
app.service('servicenName', function ($http) {
 this.getData = function () {
  return $http.get("../send");
 };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```